# Office 365 .NET Languages

Tags: office-365

General Question: What .net language should I be learning since my organization has me learning and developing on SharePoint for Office 365. Not sure if there a difference. I was partial to VB or C#.﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you're working with Microsoft products and/or web-based applications, you probably want to go with C#. For the  most part, if you know VB or C#, it's fairly easy to translate back and forth from one to the other. And although either language will work quite nicely with SharePoint, the product itself is built using C#.

In fact, there are three languages you probably should learn when working on any kind of SharePoint or web-based application:

- C# : Used for workflows, adding ribbon functionality, menu actions, etc. in SharePoint
- JavaScript : Used heavily throughout SharePoint (usually for interface functionality)
- jQuery : SharePoint 2013 and SP Online allow you to customize your web parts using jQuery. In many ways, this replaces the XSLT coding found in previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a preference then go with C#. Not because it's better than VB but because all of the code in documentation, training, blogs, videos, etc. is going to be written in C#.